# T-SQL/SQL- Copy Value From One Column to Another in View Depending on Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I have a problem. I will try to show it on Northwind database.
https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com

I want to make a view on "Customer" table, where the "Region" column has an alias of "Country", but I will have values from "Region" column in "Country" column. I show it with "ContactName" column.

I made it like this:

```
CREATE VIEW test AS
SELECT ContactName, Region AS Country FROM Customers
```

Now i want to make a modification. I want to "copy" value from "Region" to "Country" if it is not null/not empty. If it is I want to keep value from Country.

I don't know if it's possible to make in view and using aliases and case.

Comment: `SELECT ContactName, ISNULL(Region, Country) AS Country FROM Customers`

Comment: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at SQL Server Pro [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) and MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx). It's worth reading up on the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`.  `ISNULL` will look at the first argument and if it is NULL, goes to the second argument.

```
SELECT ContactName, ISNULL(Region,Country) AS Country FROM Customers
```